# NPM does not allow installation of any packages like react

Tags: node.js, npm, npx

I have been trying to install react on my PC. The problem is that it always shows the following error:

> ```
> D:\React JS>npm install react
> npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
> npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
> npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/react failed, reason getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND host
> npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
> npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
> npm ERR! network
> npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
> npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly,  See: 'npm help config'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\Idea1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-16T12_57_52_202Z-debug.log
> ```

This is the issue, when I tried installing react or any other package.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
npm config delete proxy
```

then install command

Comment: No bro,i am not using any proxy